# Get edge lenghts as spatial distances in a network in R

Tags: r, networking, spatial

I have a list of nodes with spatial coordinates `nodes_geo`. The first column is the nodes' identifier, the other 2 columns are the x and y coordinates:

```
nodes_geo <- structure(list(grid_grid.g9.nodes = c(27, 28, 29, 40, 41, 42, 
43, 55, 56, 58, 69, 81, 94, 98, 108, 110, 113, 114, 123, 124, 
128, 138, 139, 141), grid_grid.coords.x1 = c(15.504078, 15.704078, 
15.904078, 15.104078, 15.304078, 15.504078, 15.704078, 15.104078, 
15.304078, 15.704078, 14.904078, 14.304078, 13.904078, 14.704078, 
13.704078, 14.104078, 14.704078, 14.904078, 13.704078, 13.904078, 
14.704078, 13.704078, 13.904078, 14.304078), grid_grid.coords.x2 = c(43.835623, 
43.835623, 43.835623, 44.035623, 44.035623, 44.035623, 44.035623, 
44.235623, 44.235623, 44.235623, 44.435623, 44.635623, 44.835623, 
44.835623, 45.035623, 45.035623, 45.035623, 45.035623, 45.235623, 
45.235623, 45.235623, 45.435623, 45.435623, 45.435623)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-24L))
```

And I have an adjacency matrix for these nodes `adjacency_matrix`:

```
adjacency_matrix <- structure(c(0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 
1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 
1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 
0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 
1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 
1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), .Dim = c(24L, 24L), .Dimnames = list(
    c("27", "28", "29", "40", "41", "42", "43", "55", "56", "58", 
    "69", "81", "94", "98", "108", "110", "113", "114", "123", 
    "124", "128", "138", "139", "141"), c("27", "28", "29", "40", 
    "41", "42", "43", "55", "56", "58", "69", "81", "94", "98", 
    "108", "110", "113", "114", "123", "124", "128", "138", "139", 
    "141")))
```

I would like to get the spatial lenght of edges in a network based on the above adjacency matrix. I would also like to be able to do the same from random networks generated from the real network with the same number of edges. The goal is to compare the mean edge lenght of the real network and that of the random networks for hypothesis testing.

Comment: Are your coordinates geographic longitude,latitude or planar x,y? If you have planar coordinates I think you can do something quite easy using the spatstat package.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. They are of class sfc, from what I understand this means that they are geographic coordinates.

Comment: A sfc can have any kind of coordinates, but if you started with geographic and didn't do any transform then they are geographic. It seems they span over a big area, but if you can find an acceptable planar projection then you can use spatstat to do what you want. Is it ok to project to flat space?

Comment: Ah ok, yes they cover the north-eastern adriatic coast. I don't see any problem with a plannar projection.

Comment: It is possible that you might be interested in the sfnetworks package. It combines sf with tidygraph, an API to igraph. I am not exactly sure of what you mean by network based, could it be OpenStreetMap? Then you could look into osmextract or osmdata to get the network and transform it into an sfnetwork ;)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a starting point using the data from above (note that we assue these
coordinates are planar with Euclidean distances, so you should really project
first):

```r
library(spatstat)
nodes_ppp <- as.ppp(nodes_geo[,c(2:3,1)], W = bounding.box.xy(nodes_geo[,-1]))
head(as.data.frame(nodes_ppp))
#>          x        y marks
#> 1 15.50408 43.83562    27
#> 2 15.70408 43.83562    28
#> 3 15.90408 43.83562    29
#> 4 15.10408 44.03562    40
#> 5 15.30408 44.03562    41
#> 6 15.50408 44.03562    42
a_mat <- adjacency_matrix > 0 # Logical matrix required
typeof(adjacency_matrix)
#> [1] "double"
typeof(a_mat)
#> [1] "logical"
network <- linnet(nodes_ppp, a_mat) # Linear network
#> Warning: Network is not connected
plot(network)
```

[image]

```r
segs <- as.psp(network) # Segments of linear network
rslt <- lengths_psp(segs) # Segment lengths
hist(rslt)
```

[image]